# Cannot install IBM Eclipse tools for Bluemix due to network issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I'm trying to install [IBM Eclipse tools for Bluemix](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-eclipse-tools-bluemix) but getting this error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Unable to read repository at
>   http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/kepler/plugins/com.ibm.ws.st.common.core_1.0.100.v20150220_1740.jar.
>   Connection reset

I tried to use solution from this dW Answers post [Downloading Bluemix plugin for Eclipse... Is it even possible???](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/29157/downloading-bluemix-plugin-for-eclipse-is-it-even-possible.html) but it didn't help.

When I went and tried to manually download file by using this link : http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/kepler/plugins/com.ibm.ws.st.common.core_1.0.100.v20150220_1740.jar I get an error:

> This webpage is not available

But when I changed link to use **https** as following, it works:
https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/kepler/plugins/com.ibm.ws.st.common.core_1.0.100.v20150220_1740.jar

So, my question is how can I redirect all "problematic" links to correct web site? In other words, is it possible to one url to another url? 
Thank you.

**UPDATE**:

*Tried to install this plugin at home and everything worked. I suspect that something wrong with a network on a work, will ask our admins to try to investigate the issue and post it back if we'll discover something interesting.*

**UPDATE 2**
*Confirmed by admins. It was a temporary network issue.*

Comment: There's more than one solution posted there. Which did you do? One of them? All of them?

Comment: Actually I tried to add i  the following to eclipse.ini: -`Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`, second solution by using **p2/update site content** I didn't use because it looks like a bit hacky solution, trying to avoid such workarounds.

Comment: Which solution worked for you?

Comment: @JeffSloyer, I tried first one, to run eclipse with ipv4stack = true but it didn't work. I didn't try another solution right now, explained in previous comment why.

Comment: Can you try another solution? It seems to be a networking and eclipse issue....

Comment: @JeffSloyer, see my update it was really network issue and it looks like unrelated to Eclipse at all. I'll try to talk with admins tomorrow and then update my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Anatoly checking back in on this...

Answer (score 1):

here is the last updated guide for Eclipse Bluemix tool plugin, which should be always used to install this plugin for the first time, in order to be sure on using the right version
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html#eclipsetools

At the following url a shorted version with Eclipse installation link:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/deploy_eclipsetools.html

Your issue could be related to an obsolete reference updated with a new release version for the plugin.